# Message box, search, copy and paste to new worksheet and repeat

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code I am using for my excel spreadsheet "Product Database". It works fine, I just need it to continue "looping" in a way. After I search for the product I am looking for is the message box, it copies and pastes it to another worksheet and it goes down one row. Then when I search again, it erases what I previously searched for.

here is the code:

```
Sub Test2()
Dim myWord$
myWord = InputBox("What key word to copy rows", "Enter your word")
If myWord = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xRow&, NextRow&, LastRow&
NextRow = 2
LastRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchORder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For xRow = 1 To LastRow
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(xRow), "*" & myWord & "*") > 0 Then
Rows(xRow).Copy Sheets("Heather").Rows(NextRow)
NextRow = NextRow + 1
End If
Next xRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Macro is complete, " & NextRow - 2 & " rows containing" & vbCrLf & _
"''" & myWord & "''" & " were copied to Heather.", 64, "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `NextRow = 2` so every time it count from 2.
Use blow code-

```
NextRow = Sheets("Heather").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

However you can change column(A) as per need.